# gcloud alpha monitoring policies create --policy-from-file throws error "must specify a restriction on "resource.type" in the filter"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-monitoring

I've created a couple alert policies using cloud console, but after exporting them and changing name (via Download JSON or gcloud CLI) I can't import them back.

Details below:

Payload (name fields are removed after export):

```
{
  "displayName": "somename",
  "conditions": [
    {
      "displayName": "somename",
      "conditionAbsent": {
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "alignmentPeriod": "300s",
            "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_MEAN",
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_DELTA"
          }
        ],
        "duration": "300s",
        "filter": "metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/user/some-metric\""
      }
    }
  ],
  "combiner": "OR",
  "enabled": true,
  "notificationChannels": [
    "projects/my-prod-dod/notificationChannels/1962880049684990238",
    "projects/my-prod-dod/notificationChannels/9131919367771592634"
  ]
}
```

Command:

```
gcloud alpha monitoring policies create --policy-from-file alert.json
```

Error:

```
Field alert_policy.conditions[0].condition_absent.filter had an invalid value of "metric.type="logging.googleapis.com/user/some-metric"": must specify a restriction on "resource.type" in the filter
```

Metric type is:

[image]

Screenshot of alert policy:
[image]

Comment: As you have self resolved issue,  please accept the solution you have posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding additional filter like below solved the problem

```
"filter": "metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/user/celery-person\" resource.type=\"k8s_container\"",
```

Similar question:
[Use a Stackdriver resource group's ID in a GCP Deployment Manager configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57305803/use-a-stackdriver-resource-groups-id-in-a-gcp-deployment-manager-configuration)